# How do "scrawl" and "scribble" differ?

Tags: word-difference

Definition of *scrawl* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scrawl):

> to write awkwardly, carelessly, or illegibly.

Definition of *scribble* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scribble?s=t):

> to write or draw in a hasty or careless way.

The definition of *scribble* is actually exactly the same as the earliest definition of this question. You use "scribble" to describe something that is written awkwardly, carelessly or illegibly. Likewise, the word *scrawl* also shares the meaning of writing hastily or carelessly.

So what is the difference between them? I can't differentiate them by dictionary definitions or Google search.

---

**EDIT:** Definition of *scrawl* by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrawl):

> :  to write **or draw** awkwardly, hastily, or carelessly scrawled his name

Comment: The difference is that [scribble](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scribble) can take two objects.

Answer (score 2):

*scrawl* is usually related to writing (or what is supposed to be writing), while *scribble* can be any kind of markings.

See [*scribble*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scribble):

> 2. *verb*
>      To scribble means to make meaningless marks or rough drawings using a pencil or pen.
>      *When Caroline was five she scribbled on a wall.*

If you check the definitions of [*scrawl*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrawl), they all refer to writing in some way.

Also, adults tend to *scrawl* (it is usually intentional), while children tend to *scribble* (they are careless or haven't learned how to write or draw yet).

Comment: oh, sorry, I just added definition of scrawl by Merriam-Webster. Is your answer still stands that "scrawl" is usually related to writing?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two pictures to illustrate these meanings:

1. Scrawling
   [image]
2. Scribbling
   [image]

However, when speaking about adults' manner of writing we can use these words as synonyms:

> He scrawled his signature. (= His signature looked like a squiggle.)
>
> I scribbled my name at the bottom of the page.(= I wrote my name very
>   quickly, so it looked unreadable.)

Comment: I've just been voted down. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer to restore your rep unless someone comes here and invalidate your answer.